# Can a cryptocurrency be liquid while it is in its pre-sale, or even ICO

Tags: litecoin, currencies, ethereum, cryptography

I am planning to run a Coin's ICO for several years, not interested in the gains to be made from selling out ICO in 3 days NO, but interested in using the COin to end Global Poverty as i deem fit. So a lenghty ICO is one solution. That said I want to know if its possible for the coin to be liquid during the ICO of like 2-4 years. If it is possible for its liquidity then suggest how that can be done please.

Answer (score 1):

It could, but liquidity during ICO (meaning you can buy and sell tokens before ICO ends) could lead to many economical problems. For instance, if people could buy your token on exchange - they will not buy it on ICO, so you will not get  funds you need for the project.